# Why do I have a group shape error on python pptx for one shape?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I am trying to write a programme to update hyperlinks in a powerpoint file. The hyperlinks are embedded in several images within the pptx.

I used a part of the script from the python pptx wiki but I get the following error: TypeError: a group shape cannot have a click action

I understand a group shape cannot have a hyperlink but in my case, it should only be one shape.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

```
       prs = Presentation("My file")
       slides = [slide for slide in prs.slides]
       shapes = []
        for slide in slides:
            for shape in slide.shapes:
                shapes.append(shape)

        for slide in prs.slides:
            for shape in slide.shapes:
                click_action = shape.click_action
                if click_action.action == PP_ACTION.HYPERLINK:
                    print(click_action.hyperlink)
```

TypeError: a group shape cannot have a click action

Answer (score 1):

The following allows you to determine whether the shape in question is a group:

```
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE

if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP:
    print("Yep, it's a group-shape alright.")
```

There's nothing preventing a group from only having a single member, so this could be the situation you've encountered. You can enumerate the "subshapes" in a group with this:

```
if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP:
    group_shape = shape
    print("Subshapes are:")
    for s in group_shape.shapes:
        print("    %s" % s.shape_type)
```

Another thing is that pictures do not have a text-frame like other shapes. So if someone wanted a text URL to display on a picture they would have to add a textbox shape to hold it and might very well then group the two so they could be moved around together. This might also explain the situation you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very useful. I can see the subshapes now. Actually, the text isn't displayed on the picture, but when the user clicks on the picture, it opens a webpage. I tried to create another for loop to access each single shape so that  click_action = shape.click_action doesn't return an error but I didn't succeed... Actually the program iterates through many powerpoint presentations, might that be the cause of it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If this answers your question, please accept the answer. That's how the stackoverflow economy works. If this answer has led you to a _new_ question, please post that question separately.