# How to get the text content in the combined shape in the PPT

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

```
from pptx import Presentation
import time

prs = Presentation(r'D:\ppt_files\Mathematics courseware.pptx')
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            text_frame = shape.text_frame
            print(text_frame.text)
```

I can use the code above to get part of the text content in the PPT file, but I find that if there are text boxes and other shapes combined together, then the text content cannot be read. How to solve this problem?

Comment: By "combined together" I'm guessing you mean grouped. If so, you'd need to test to see if the shape's .Type = 6 (ie, it's a group) and if so, iterate through the shape's .GroupItems collection.

Comment: I am a beginner, do you have the code?

Comment: See if the answer to this earlier question gives you what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58437903/1902513

Comment: @mincla I don't do python so I can't help with the code. Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem